# Move the edit widget on the left side on the mobile app

Tags: discussion, edits, ios-app, user-card

On the web interface when Alice edits Bob’s question, the Alice’a profile widget will appear on the left. On the mobile app it appears on the right, pushing the Bob’s widget on the left.

I found this quite confusing because I usually use the web interface and I know what’s on the left is the widget of the user who edited the question.

I’ve been using the mobile iOS app for about an year and still didn’t get used to it.

Here is a screenshot of the components I’m referring to:

[image]

To me it seems like a small inconsistency, but I’m wondering what you think.

Is there a specific reason to keep it this way?

Comment: @ShadowWizard The little rectangle containing the avatar, username, reputation and the badges of the user.

Comment: Oh, so it's known as "user card". Still, screenshot of how it looks like in the iOS app would be a good idea, not many people got the app so it's hard to see what you mean.

Comment: So, the thing is, the app is pretty much all left aligned. I'm not sure that anything is right aligned at all... so making this change would mess up how people expect the app to look.

Comment: @Catija I added a screenshot making it clearer what I want. I don’t think this would unbalance the things.